# ItemUpdated event handler not working

Tags: 2007, list, event-handlers

I added a ItemUpdated event handler so what happens is when I upload a document it uploads it and takes me straight to edit item page, where I can made changes. now if I make any changes to it, no event triggers.

what i actually did is created a custom column in list, so that it tells if a customer has been paid bonus or not, so when I upload a document of pay slip it is suppose to check the property if property is checked it should add an entry to DB if not then nothing will happen but

if i use

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
```

it triggers event before actually taking me to edit item properties so I can't check property as user didn't been to edit item page, however now if i edit properties of item it doesn't triggers updateItem event handler

Comment: could you please show some of the ItemUpdated code to know where its going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try IISreset it works most times :)

hope it helps !